# After javascript addclass it adds class but css property not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Can please someone help me?

Here .header-line after scroll has an additional class of .header-line .active but css can't see it and doesn't change the background-color. You can see my css and there .header-line .active is with background-color property. Why is my background still transparent?

CSS:

```
.header-line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.00);
}
.header-line .active {
  background-color: white;
}
```

header:

```
<div class="header-line">header</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
  $(window).on("scroll", function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
      $(".header-line").addClass("active");
    } else {
      //remove the background property so it comes transparent again (defined in your css)
      $(".header-line").removeClass("active");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: please edit and paste relevant code here. It is not possible to debug from webpage

Comment: Please include any relevant markup, JavaScript and CSS in your question, see: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is because in your css file you have `.header-line .active { ... }`, and that means `.active` class inside `.header-line` class.

You should change that to `.headerline.active { ... }` (remove the space)

Comment: Not sure why the question got voted down.  It's a perfectly valid question, representing the same problem I came here to find an answer for, and with this answer, I found it.  SO's voting system is irreversibly broken, IMO.  Thanks!  This solved the same problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the css like this in your bootstarp.css

```
.header-line.active {
background-color: white;
}
```